# How use apex attribute of type Sobject

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, attribute

I am building a visualforce component where I have:

```
 <apex:attribute name="objectName" description="An Sobject" type="Sobject" required="false"/>  
<apex:attribute name="ChildName" description="Child Relationship" type="String" required="false"/>
```

I would like to refer "objectName" in my Visualforce page like:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="acc">   
<c:recorddisplay childName="Account" objectName="{!acc}"/>
</apex:page>
```

But when I try to use objectName="{!acc}" in my VF page it says:

> `<c:recorddisplay objectName="{!acc}">`. Expected Sobject, found Account[]

Comment: Can you post your controller? You're doing things the right way but it seems as though your controller doesn't have a property called `Contact`. Are you using a standard controller?

Comment: I am using - <apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="acc">, Just added it. But when I try to use objectName="{!acc}" in my VF page it says - <c:recorddisplay objectName="{!acc}">. Expected Sobject, found Account[]

Comment: Updated your quesiton based on your comment. For the original issue with "Contact" not being allowed, accounts don't have a Contact property, but they do have Contacts (plural). You'd need to loop over `Account.Contacts` in a similar manner to the Account loop in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is you're using a Standard List Controller, which deals with multiple records as opposed to a Standard Controller which operates on a single SObject.

The variable you assign to the `recordSetVar` parameter is an array of objects of the type specficied, so in your case `acc` is an array of accounts, hence the mismatched type error.

You can either ditch the `recordSetVar="acc"` property if you just want to work with one account and do:

```
<c:recorddisplay objectName="{!Account}"/>
```

or loop over the accounts:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!acc}" var="a">
    <c:recordddisplay objectName="{!a}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

`objectName` doesn't seem like a great name for the parameter, consider calling it `record` or something instead.